# Storing SESSION variables as CONSTANTS

Tags: php, arrays, constants, session-variables

More a general query this than anything else but would be interestEed in hearing what the general consensus might be.

I have user session data stored in a session user array as is usual. Obviously I can access that array directly on each page that includes session_start(). However I'd like to be able to access the session items using simple variables rather than referencing the array each time. Really what it comes down to is less typing for me but also neater code.

I was thinking of including a file at the top of each page that defines each session variable as a constant and then I could reference the constant rather than the array.

Would this work or would it cause issues if more than one user is logged in?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Yes it would work but i don't think that's a very good idea

Comment: Why do you want to do it? I think is totally unnecessary. But anyway, there is another way, if you create a class for it, and then use that class to get out the session variables.

Comment: Valid questions and I appreciate that it's kind of redundant but what I want to do is be able to type something like <?php echo USERNAME; ?> rather than <?php echo $_SESSION['user']['username]; ?>. It's more a curiousity I have as I step my way through learning the best practises of developing with PHP.

Comment: Just a spontaneous thought. Since constants can be defined only once, what would happen if a value in the session changed, i.e. get overwritten? I can only second @lolka_bolka - write a class to represent the session. To get an idea about, have a look at some frameworks (in a few of them the class is called Registry).

Comment: Good point, users can update their email details and some other details too. Yeah, I think that will cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it would work! But i think that's not a good idea/ it's unnecessary.

As an example that it works:

index.php:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = "myuser1233";

    require_once("config.php");
    echo USERNAME;

?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php

    //session_start(); you would have to start the session if you don't start the session in the file which includes this one
    define("USERNAME", $_SESSION['username']);

?>
```

Output:

```
myuser1233
```

(I would use the session itself or make a class with the session values because what do you do if the value change? you can't overwrite a constant!)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it was a silly question now that I have engaged in discussion regarding it. Certian user details won't change but there's little point in referencing some as constants and some using the session array. As for classes, while I've used existing classes and can understand them I have yet to roll me own. This could be a good exercise for doing just that. Onwards with the learning!